# Get MibModule Object or Entity from ObjectIdentifier [SharpSNMPLib]

Tags: snmp, mib, sharp-snmp

I made a Walker requesting a network device some information.

```
IPEndPoint receiver = new IPEndPoint(ip, 161);

IList<Variable> result = new List<Variable>();

WalkMode mode = WalkMode.WithinSubtree;

Messenger.Walk(VersionCode.V1, receiver, new OctetString(community), new ObjectIdentifier("1.3"), result, timeout, mode);
```

The code returns all OIDs perfectly on your device, but I needed to convert these names to OIDs. 
I saw the example that makes this translation, but it uses the compilation of MIBs, I would make this translation from the list of loaded MibModule method Parser.ParseToModules (...).

How do I link this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var modules = Parser.ParseToModules(docs, out errors, out warnings);
            var assembler = new Assembler();
            assembler.Assemble(modules);`

You can use `Assembler` class to further process the modules. `Assembler.Tree` will give you a tree (`IObjectTree`) which can be used to perform OID/name translation.

Comment: Tks Lex... But... Some values don't work translation: "SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.2.1.0:"

Comment: When translation fails, you need to check whether the proper MIB documents are loaded.